# Why does strtok with \n, only read the first line of the txt file?

Tags: c

I have had some problems with `strtok`, I am trying, in my code in C, read from a text file, however, only the fist line is being read, because for some reason, the variable `arq` becomes `NULL` after first line.

the txt:

```
ola
oi
a
b
e
z
```

code:

```
void le_arquivo(char *optarg) {
    FILE *respostas;                
    char *arq;                      
    char resp[SBUFF];              
    char *tokens[SBUFF];           
    int c = 0;

    respostas = fopen(optarg, "r");
    if (respostas == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
        return;
    }
    fgets(resp, sizeof(resp), respostas);
    arq = strtok(resp, "\n");      
    while (arq != NULL) {
        tokens[c] = arq;
        arq = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        c++;
    }
    fclose(respostas);
    organiza_dados(tokens, c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` does not read from the file, it splits the character array. By definition `fgets()` reads a single line including the trailing newline if present in the file, so `strtok()` only splits a single item. Instead of `fgets()`, you should try and read the whole file with `fread()`, and null terminate the array before the `strtok()` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void le_arquivo(char *optarg) {
    FILE *respostas;                
    char *arq;                      
    char resp[SBUFF];              
    char *tokens[SBUFF];           
    int n, c;

    respostas = fopen(optarg, "r");
    if (respostas == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
        return;
    }
    n = fread(resp, 1, sizeof(resp) - 1, respostas);
    resp[n] = '\0';
    arq = strtok(resp, "\n");
    for (c = 0; arq != NULL; c++) {
        tokens[c] = arq;
        arq = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
    fclose(respostas);
    organiza_dados(tokens, c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! That worked! i spent a couple of days in this doubt! Thank you!!!